# Does uniform boundedness principle hold for other types of operator norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $(x_\alpha^*)_\alpha$ be a net in $X^*$, where $X^*$ is the continuous dual of $X$.
For each $\alpha$, let $\|x_\alpha^*\|_{op}$ be the operator norm of $x_\alpha^*$, i.e.,
$$\|x_\alpha^*\|_{op} = \sup_{x_\alpha\in X, \|x_\alpha\|\leq 1}|x_\alpha^*(x_\alpha)|.$$

To show that
$$\sup_\alpha \|x_\alpha^*\|_{op}<\infty,$$
by the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Theorem), it suffices to show that
$$\sup_\alpha|x_\alpha^*(x)| < \infty \quad \text{for all} \quad x\in X.$$

---

I am interested whether the same arguments above hold for $x_\alpha^*$ having two components.

More precisely, for each $\alpha$, let $x_\alpha^* = (x_{\alpha 1}^*, x_{\alpha 2}^*):X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$x_\alpha^*(x_1,x_2) = x_{\alpha 1}^*(x_1) + x_{\alpha 2}^*(x_2).$$
The norm on $x_\alpha^*$ is defined by
$$\|x_\alpha^*\|_1 = \|x_{\alpha 1}^*\|_{op} + \|x_{\alpha 2}^*\|_{op}.$$
Now, suppose that $(x_\alpha^*)$ is a net in $(X\times X)^*$.
I want to show that
$$\sup_\alpha\| x_\alpha^* \|_1 < \infty.$$
Does the uniform boundedness principle hold in this case, i.e., is it sufficient to show that
$$\sup_\alpha |x_\alpha^*(x)|<\infty \quad \text{for all} \quad x = (x_1,x_2)\in X\times X?$$
To summarize, my question is,

> if
> $$\sup_\alpha |x_{\alpha 1}^*(x_1) + x_{\alpha 2}^*(x_2)| < \infty \quad \text{for all}\quad (x_1,x_2)\in X\times X,$$
> does it imply that
> $$\sup_\alpha (\|x_{\alpha 1}^*\|_{op} + \|x_{\alpha 2}^*\|_{op})<\infty?$$

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the hypothesis to $(x_1,0)$ and $(0, x_2)$. You can then apply UBP separately to the two components.

Comment: @Idonknow I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Your norm $\lVert-\rVert_1$ is the operator norm when you equip $X\times X$ with the norm $\lVert(x,y)\rVert=\max\{\lVert x\rVert,\lVert y\rVert\}$.

Comment: Does it mean that if we have different norm on $X\times X$, then UBP cannot be applied? For example, $\| x_\alpha^*\| = \left( \| x_{\alpha 1}^*\|_{op}^2 + \| x_{\alpha 2}^* \|_{op}^2\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Any norm defined on $X\times X$ of the form $\lVert(\lVert x_1\rVert_X,\lVert x_2\rVert_X)\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ are Lipschitz equivalent (since any two norms on finite-dimensional spaces (here $(\lVert x_1\rVert_X,\lVert x_2\rVert_X)\in\mathbb{R}^2$) are equivalent).